# Varying number of div layout

Tags: css

I'm trying to generate a layout which has varying number of divs, I.e.

```
   | Large | Large |
|Small | Small | Small |
   | Large | Large |
         ...
```

Large divs will have 50% width, whereas smaller one's will have 33%.

How can I go about this? I'm floating the div's so that they're in a row, but unsure on how I can get three smaller divs, below the larger ones, whilst still ensuring everything is central?

Current approach:

```css
.case-card--large {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.case-card {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 33%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="case-card case-card--large">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Dummy text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="case-card case-card--large">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Dummy text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="case-card">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Dummy text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="case-card">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Dummy text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="case-card">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Dummy text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to center stuff, then you rather don’t want to float it to begin with …

Comment: Although I don’t see what you mean with centering here to begin with - 2 * 50% and 3 * 33% always cover the full width anyway (almost), so what exactly do you want to “center” then …?

Comment: @CBroe 3*33% covers only 99% of the width.. Although you have mentioned it as almost but just for clarity: It has to be 33.33% to reach the exact width. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can work with a CSS technique: flex ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout)).

Put those elements in a parent container, set its width and make it behave as a flex-box by using `display: flex`. Here below is an example of how I did it. The CSS rules below the `/* show case rules below */` are used to have a visual result of what you can have by using flex boxes.

```css
#cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 600px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.case-card {
  width: 33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* show case rules below */
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.case-card--large {
  width: 50%;
  /* show case rules below */
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div class="case-card case-card--large">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Dummy text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case-card case-card--large">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Dummy text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case-card">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Dummy text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case-card">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Dummy text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case-card">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Dummy text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case-card case-card--large">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Dummy text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case-card case-card--large">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Dummy text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

edit: I have used `justify-content: space-around;` first which aligns the elements with `width: 33%` somewhat nicely in the middle towards each other. Changing that to `justify-content: space-between;` ensures that the outer boxes are aligned to the same border as the container which may appeal the OP more. Credits for D.Schaller

Comment: I'd suggest `justify-content:space-between`

Comment: @D.Schaller yes, that gives a better result. It depends of the end result but I think that the OP would be more satisfied with that. Edited the post.

Comment: I have a little snippet with a similiar approach, maybe u want to edit this into your answer as an alternative. [auto-sizing per subdivs in flexbox](https://codepen.io/DeeLiciouz/pen/qymKvr). 
What I did there: I used subdivs called "row" to wrap the elements on each row. Then I made them flex and told all children of "row" to be the same width, so that the width changes on count of items, so he won't have to resize if he goes for 4-5 cases per row

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.

I have used `display:inline-block` for each box

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  font-size: 0; /* to remove space betwen inline elements*/
}

.wrapper {
  font-size: initial;
}

.case-card {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.case-card--large {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="case-card case-card--large">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Dummy text Large</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case-card case-card--large">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Dummy text Large</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case-card">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Dummy text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case-card">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Dummy text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case-card">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Dummy text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case-card case-card--large">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Dummy text Large</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case-card case-card--large">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Dummy text Large</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case-card">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Dummy text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case-card">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Dummy text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case-card">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Dummy text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include box-sizing:border-box because you are using padding or to put width as width: calc(33% - 80px), also .large class create as subclass or otherwise in your case put !important, because now doesn't work and everything is width 33%

```css
body{
  text-align:center;
}

.case-card {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 33.33%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 -2px;
  
}

.case-card.large{
   width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="case-card large">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Dummy text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="case-card large">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Dummy text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="case-card">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Dummy text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="case-card">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Dummy text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="case-card">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Dummy text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. So I made little modification in the code and it works quite fine. Hope it helps you out.

Instead of `float:right` I used

> float:left

and **added the border to the wrapper class**.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oMWMBE

```
.case-card--large {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper { border: 1px solid blue; }
.case-card {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33.33%;
}

<div class="case-card--large">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <p>Dummy text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="case-card--large">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Dummy text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="case-card">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Dummy text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="case-card">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Dummy text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="case-card">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Dummy text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```